# Google Calendar Appointment Slot : Custom Functionality

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I want to use Google Calendar for a 3D Scanner appointment booking functionality. First, I would choose a appointment slot to make available for customers to book appointments, then I would take the link for the slot and make it public to the potential customers. Afterwards, different people can book appointments for the slots, however the slot is only filled when the customer comes in and pays for the scanner service in our office on a first come first serve bases.

My problem with this scenario in Google Calendar is that once the first customer books the appointment, the slot appear filled on the calendar such as below:

[image]

I don't want this, I want the slot to still be open to other customers but when the first customer books an appointment, I want to send him an email saying come to our office and pay as soon as possible for the time slot to be yours.

So now that I have described what I want, I want to investigate is this functionality possible in Google Calendar? Currently I have to manually click on the invitation email Going to? "No/Maybe" for the slot to become available for others :

[image]

Can I control this Going to option/property via app script? Is there an event handler for when appointment is booked? Any help is appreciated.

### **Update**

```
function calendarTest1() {

  // Gets the public calendar "US Holidays" by ID.
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('id_usually_email');
  //Logger.log('The calendar is named "%s".', calendar.getName());
  //Logger.log('The calendar description is "%s".', calendar.getDescription());
  var today = new Date();
  var events = calendar.getEventsForDay(today);
  //Logger.log('Number of events: ' + events.length);

  for(event in events ){

    Logger.log('Title: ' + events[event].getTitle());
    Logger.log('Start Time: ' + events[event].getStartTime().toISOString());
    Logger.log('My Status: ' + events[event].getMyStatus());
    Logger.log('Id: ' + events[event].getId());
    events[event].setMyStatus(CalendarApp.GuestStatus.NO);
    Logger.log('My Status: ' + events[event].getMyStatus());
    Logger.log('Guest List: ' + events[event].getGuestList()[0].getEmail());
    var guests = events[event].getGuestList();

    Logger.log('----------------------------------------------------------------');
  }

}
```

As per https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/event-guest#getGuestStatus(), there is a getGuestStatus() function, I need to know if there is a setGuestStatus() so I may change the status from "yes" to "no".

**Update**

So it finally worked, it turned out that you create a appointment slot its not an event or anything, but when someone comes a book on the appointment it is just a regular event then, so you just fetch that event and turn myStatus() yes -> no and it should do the trick.

[Google Calender: Modify Event Guest Status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42011696/google-calender-modify-event-guest-status)

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: I am in the process, I will update the code soon. For now I am just investigating if such functionality is possible.