# Google Calender: Modify Event Guest Status

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

In google calendar build in API for my app script.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/

What I want to do is get the get the guest of an event and change his status from "yes" to "no".

```
var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('id');
var events = calendar.getEventsForDay(today);
Logger.log('Guest Status: ' + events[0].getGuestList()[0].getGuestStatus());
```

My above code pretty much get the guest and get his status, I am looking at the API page for Event Guest:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/event-guest

It only gives you getter methods for the guest, are there any setter methods for event guest? I am looking for a method to set status for guest. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CalendarApp you are limited to the [setMyStatus](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#setMyStatus(GuestStatus)) method and you can only set the event status of the effective user.

If all users are on your domain then you could conceivably [run a service account](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2/blob/master/samples/GoogleServiceAccount.gs) with domain delegation, calling the [Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/update) via `UrlFetch` and impersonating each user, setting their "responseStatus" to "declined" for the event.